# How to `off()` the `mouseenter` and 'mouseleave` on `click` event

Tags: jquery

I have a popup it has some notes and I am showing on `mouseenter`. as well remove on `mouseleave`.

works. the problem is, when the user click on the same element, there is `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` not required. so on click, i would like to remove the `enter` `leave` listner from the element. how to do this?

here is my code :

```
var parent = element.parent(':not(.selected)'); //on clicking adding class

            element.off('mouseenter, mouseleave').on({ //not working.

                mouseenter : function () {

                    parent.removeClass('active').addClass('active')

                },

                mouseleave : function () {

                    parent.removeClass('active');
                }

            });

            element.on('click', function () {

                var parent = element.parent();

                var text = element.next().text();
                var addedText = $('.rowOption').text();

                if( text === addedText ) {

                    $('.rowOption').toggleClass('active');
                    parent.toggleClass('selected'); //need to add and remove he `enter and leave`
                    return;

                }

                $('.rowOption').addClass('active').text( text );
                parent.siblings().removeClass('selected').end().addClass('selected');

            });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `one()`???  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: ***mouseenter*** event is triggered before ***click*** event.

Comment: Means? I have multiple elements here. user can click back to the same element too.. so i want to switch off temprorly

Comment: @lgwe Kalu.. I agree. what would be the correct way to come up with?

Comment: switching off cannot resolve the issue because the event is already fired before you would have the chance to switch it off

Comment: @A.Wolff - as like your suggestion, it's not works.

Comment: you need to implement a debounce mechanism. Here's a simple one: on ***mouseenter*** set a flag like `mayShowPopover = true;` then wrap the rest of the ***mouseenter*** handler procedure inside a `if(mayShowPopover){ /* rest of mounter handling code */ }` and queue it in a `setTimeout`. In the ***click*** event handler if `mayShowPopover` evaluates to `true` flip it back to `false`.

Comment: @user2024080, I'll add answer to demonstrate my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove comma, use `element.off('mouseenter mouseleave')`. Events should be separated by space.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp) is a reference.

Your code will be

```
var parent = element.parent(':not(.selected)'); //on clicking adding class

    element.off('mouseenter mouseleave').on({ //Change space separation from comma separation.

        mouseenter : function () {

            parent.removeClass('active').addClass('active')

        },

        mouseleave : function () {

            parent.removeClass('active');
        }

    });

    element.on('click', function () {

        var parent = element.parent();

        var text = element.next().text();
        var addedText = $('.rowOption').text();

        if( text === addedText ) {

            $('.rowOption').toggleClass('active');
            parent.toggleClass('selected'); //need to add and remove he `enter and leave`
            return;

        }

        $('.rowOption').addClass('active').text( text );
        parent.siblings().removeClass('selected').end().addClass('selected');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a ***mouseenter*** will be fired before a ***click*** event. Here I demonstrate how you may implement a *debounce* as I suggested in my comment:

```
var parent = element.parent(':not(.selected)');
var mayShowPopover;

element.on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    // maybe popover would be useful but we are not sure yet
    mayShowPopover = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      // if there was a click event just after mouse enter,
      // this code will be executed after handling the click event.
      // And if the click event did not cancel the flag, then it's OK
      // to go on and activate the popover
      if (mayShowPopover) {
        parent.removeClass('active').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    parent.removeClass('active');
  }
});

element.on('click', function() {
  var parent = element.parent();
  var text = element.next().text();
  var addedText = $('.rowOption').text();

  if (text === addedText) {
    $('.rowOption').toggleClass('active');
    parent.toggleClass('selected'); //need to add and remove he `enter and leave`
    return;
  }

  $('.rowOption').addClass('active').text(text);
  parent.siblings().removeClass('selected').end().addClass('selected');

  // cancle potential activation of popover.
  mayShowPopover = false;
});
```